# GC overhead limit exceeded when reading large xls file

Tags: java, apache-poi, jxl

When I run my project in Netbeans IDE (compiling it and testing it), it works fine. It enables me reading xls file with size of 25000 rows and extract all the infromation above, then save them into database.

The problem appears when I generate the installer and deliver it. When I install my application and run it, I obtain that error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at jxl.read.biff.File.read(File.java:217)
    at jxl.read.biff.Record.getData(Record.java:117)
    at jxl.read.biff.CellValue.<init>(CellValue.java:94)
    at jxl.read.biff.LabelSSTRecord.<init>(LabelSSTRecord.java:53)
    at jxl.read.biff.SheetReader.read(SheetReader.java:412)
    at jxl.read.biff.SheetImpl.readSheet(SheetImpl.java:716)
    at jxl.read.biff.WorkbookParser.getSheet(WorkbookParser.java:257)
    at com.insy2s.importer.SemapExcelImporter.launchImport(SemapExcelImporter.java:82)
    at//staff
```

I even user POI libraries but I got same scenario.

UPDATE:

In *messages.log* file of my application, I found this strange values (I have **changed** them in *netbeans.conf*)

```
Input arguments:
    -Xms24m
    -Xmx64m
    -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
    -Dnetbeans.user.dir=C:\Program Files\insy2s_semap_app
    -Djdk.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05
    -Dnetbeans.home=C:\Program Files\insy2s_semap_app\platform
```

Comment: Looks like your production environment (maybe client?) needs to execute this app with more memory. But let me warn you, working with Excels in Java consumes **a lot** of memory, specially large files.

Comment: Increase the VM allocated/maximum memory.For large excel file you should be using SXSSF  and not the old HSSF way which tends to give issues around the 30k? rows mark.

Comment: I will try using SXSSF. But the key question remains "why it works fine in Netbeans?". Even i have increased the memory but in vain

Comment: There is no relation with Netbeans over here.It depends upon your underlying JVM memory allocations settings. For your Netbeans JVM, you are having sufficient memory(heap size) but client machine's JVM don't have that much. That's why you are facing this issue. Check your Netbeans JVM heap size and client machine JVM heap size and make it same, It must work.

Comment: @AnkitSharma please have a look at my question again (updated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got the answer... Let's begin from the beginning.

It is true that Microsoft documents hanlders' libraries need much resources but not so bad to cause application running failure as I thought at the beginning. In fact, that probleme has revealed to me a weakness and a shortage.

Because of working with Netbeans 8.0.2, the new property

> app.conf

should be taken into consideration. It has all what needed to configure our applications.
But it is not possible to edit it directly so to increase the max permitted memory, we have to change the values in

> harness/etc/app.conf

in netbeans installation directory. For more details look [here](https://anchialas.wordpress.com/tag/app-conf/).